# AsyncTask Doesn't Resume When Coming Back to Activity Through ActionBar Back Icon

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have an `AsyntTask` which starts in `onCreate` and loops infinitely, updating an UI element.

The update is done in this manner (simplified representation of the Async extending class, let's call it `asyncExtender().execute()`):

```
doInBackground(){
    while (!isCancelled()) {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        publishProgress(someValue);
    }
}
protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    // UI update here, e.g. TextView.setText
}
```

Another activity is started, let's call it SecondActivity. SecondActivity takes advantage of the hierarchical back button in the action bar to return to the previous activity (`NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` in `onOptionsItemSelected`).

The issues is that when I tap on the back button **in the action bar** in SecondActivity, the AsyncTask seems to not run anymore in the first activity (the UI doesn't get updated every 2 seconds). On the other hand, if I use **the hardware "back" button it works fine** - the AsyncTask keeps running.

Why the difference in behaviour and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTasks should not be started simultanously and they also are not designed to be run for too long, at most few seconds. Depending which API you target, AsyncTasks might be run synchronously, so your new AsyncTask will be run only when all previous ones finished, excerpt for docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.

Comment: And what is your suggestion, besides using a service, which I think will be an overkill for such simple scenarios (with the manifest declaration and so on)?

Comment: either use ExecutorService or read link I provided, AsyncTask can be enabled to run in parallel - this might be even better idea - just to check if this is the root cause of your problem